# Modify a json array in hidden input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" id="paidIds" name="paidIds" value="[]">
```

It starts with an empty array as its value.
I want to add and remove items from it but I cant work out how.
This is my code so far:
TO APPEND:

```
var $paidIds = $('#paidIds').val();
$paidIds.push($id);
$('#paidIds').val($paidIds);
```

TO REMOVE:

```
var $paidIds = $('#paidIds').val();
var $index = paidIds.indexOf($id);
if($index != -1) {
    $('#paidIds').val().splice($index, 1);
}
$('#paidIds').val($paidIds);
```

So far one of the issues is $paidIds is still undefined after:

```
var $paidIds = $('#paidIds').val();
```

At a loss, and google is not helping -__-

**EDIT**
Got it working partly, in the debugger $paidIds = [4] but it did not set the value.

```
var $paidIds = JSON.parse($('#paidIds').val());
$paidIds.push($id);
$paidIds = JSON.stringify($paidIds)
$('#paidIds').val($paidIds);
```

**EDIT2** fixed the missing #

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert string to object.

Change:

```
$('paidIds').val()
```

to

```
$('#paidIds').val()
```

Try:

```
var $paidIds = $('#paidIds').val();
if($paidIds != ""){
    $paidIds = JSON.parse($paidIds);
}
```

Comment: still has invalid selector

Comment: Tried it but getting a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u" error on this line `var $paidIds = JSON.parse($('paidIds').val());`

Comment: Thanks fixed the selector typo.

Comment: Nvm was my selector typo again

Answer (score 1):

try to use `JSON.parse` when you read from the input, and use `JSON.stringify` when you set the input's value

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you store array an a `data-` attribute and use `jQuery.data()` to read it rather than parsing the value to an array.

HTML

```
<input id="paidIds" name="paidIds" data-array="[1,2,3]" value="[1,2,3]">
```

JS

```
/* Custom event to handle updates*/    
 $('#paidIds').on('updateArray', function (evt, newVal) {
     var arr = $(this).data('array');
     arr.push(newVal);
     $(this).val(JSON.stringify(arr))
 });

/* Useage*/
 $('button').click(function () {
      var newArrValue=$(this).data('val')
     $('#paidIds').trigger('updateArray', [newArrValue]);
 });
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tPw5y/1/)**</kbd>